# Database Design For Historical Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of employers(Table A). I want to create a similar table with an extra date column(Table B), showing the date the rows were inserted. I want to insert the rows from Table A to the new table at the end of every month. Is there a way to automate this in SQL?

I have heard that you can do this through stored procedures, but I don't have any experience using them and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the table may look like:

```
MemberID First Last   Department Salary Daily_Hours Active_Flag
100      Evan  Turner Sales      75000  8           1
200      Ron   Gold   Marketing  80000  9           1
300      Bob   Gun    HR         50000  8           1
```

Desired output:

```
ID MemberID First Last   Department Salary Daily_Hours Active_Flag Date
1  100      Evan  Turner Sales      75000  8           1           3/31/19
2  200      Ron   Gold   Marketing  80000  9           1           3/31/19
3  300      Bob   Gun    HR         50000  8           1           3/31/19
4  100      Evan  Turner Sales      75000  8           1           4/30/19
5  200      Ron   Gold   Marketing  80000  9           1           4/30/19
6  300      Bob   Gun    HR         50000  8           1           4/30/19
7  100      Evan  Turner Finance    95000  8           1           5/31/19
8  200      Ron   Gold   Marketing  80000  9           1           5/31/19
9  300      Bob   Gun    HR         60000  8           1           5/31/19
```

Note how Evan Turner has changed department and received a salary bump on the month of May. Bob got a salary increase in the same month as well

The idea is that table A gets updated once every month and I want to record that change into the new table.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the `insert`, or how to schedule such a thing?

Comment: From a design point of view, this is not a good solution. I would advise that you use a `VALID_FROM` and `VALID_TO` date, and only add a new row (and update the previous one) if there is a change. You can then set up a trigger on the base table to automatically do the work (no scheduling needed)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a procedure like below and schedule it every month end.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertHistory
AS
BEGIN

IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = CAST(EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS DATE)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO HistoryTable
(
  Id
  ,MemberId
  ,First
  ,Last
  ,Department
  ,Salary
  ,Daily_Hours
  ,Active_Flag
  ,Date
)
SELECT   Id
  ,MemberId
  ,First
  ,Last
  ,Department
  ,Salary
  ,Daily_Hours
  ,Active_Flag
  ,GETDATE()
FROM Table

END

END
```

Comment: a TRIGGER would be soo much nicer! (an have more added value)

Comment: Yes. But the initial expectation is to retain the complete data set at end of every month. I would have more than agreed for a trigger in case of only tracking changes but not the complete set

Comment: Thanks @Dheerendra. This is what I want. I originally started with a trigger to record the changes, but if someone from my team messes up and makes two updates on the same rows, then we may get two records for the same month, which is not what I want. I only care about the complete set of changes

Comment: making sure you have all the changes (via a TRIGGER) gives you also the complete set at the end of a month.

Comment: @Luuk You are right. The thing is that I only want one record for each employer every month because I need this table to grab other stats from other tables. Having multiple records for the same employer in the same month would add unnecessary duplicates

Comment: You history table will grow 'fast' with row that also exist in your employers table. A trigger can also be mad to update a record if that already exists within a certain month, leaving you with max 1 record per employee in a month, and 0 records for employees with no mutations in that month

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column that records when a row is inserted:

```
alter table t add column createdAt datetime default getdate();
```

This will be automatically populated with the insertion date (moving forward).